# what is the XSL to convert the following xml to another xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file of below format:

```
 -<table>
      <A>
        <a>x</a>
        <b>y</b>
      </A>
       <B>
       ...
       ...
       ....
      </B>
       <C>
       ...
       ...
       ...
       </C>
    </table>
```

I want to make "A" as a root node instead of table. Is there any way to code in xsl so that the above xml looks like below?

```
 <A a="x" b="y">
      <B>
      ...
      ...
      ...
     </B>
      <C>
      ...
      ...
      ...
     </C>
     </A>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <A>
   <xsl:for-each select="A/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::A)]"/>
 </A>
</xsl:template>
```